# Can git only store evolution of filename and size instead of files?

Tags: git

I want to track the evolution of files (mostly video/audio) inside a directory. I decided to use git but since each file is pretty huge (~50Go) I only want to save the evolution of filename and size between commits for analytic purposes.

I checked [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) but this solution store the entire file in the database which will take too much space. Is there a way to only store the evolution of filename and space of the files inside this folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)?

> git-annex allows managing files with git, without checking the file contents into git. While that may seem paradoxical, it is useful when dealing with files larger than git can currently easily handle, whether due to limitations in memory, time, or disk space.